# Downloading with ansible get_url module a file behind CDN gives a 403

Tags: automation, ansible

Im trying to download a package with ansible task:

```yaml
- name: Download File 
  get_url:
    url: "https://releases.jfrog.io/artifactory/jfrog-distribution/distribution-deb/2.22.2/jfrog-distribution-2.22.2-deb.tar.gz" 
    dest: "/tmp/jfrog-distribution-2.22.2-deb.tar.gz"
```

```
fatal: [server]: FAILED! => {
  "changed": false, 
  "dest": "/tmp/jfrog-distribution-2.22.2-deb.tar.gz",
  "elapsed": 80,
  "msg": "Request failed",
  "response": "HTTP Error 403: Forbidden",
  "status_code": 403,
  "url": "https://releases.jfrog.io/artifactory/jfrog-distribution/distribution-deb/2.22.2/jfrog-distribution-2.22.2-deb.tar.gz"
}
```

I have no problems downloading with curl from the same machine:

```bash
curl -L "https://releases.jfrog.io/artifactory/jfrog-distribution/distribution-deb/2.22.2/jfrog-distribution-2.22.2-deb.tar.gz>" -o jfrog-distribution-2.22.2-deb.tar.gz
```

I've tried using `uri` module with `follow_redirects: yes`.

But I've got another error fatal:

```
[server]: FAILED! => {
  "changed": false, 
  "dest": "/tmp/jfrog-distribution-2.22.2-deb.tar.gz", 
  "elapsed": 80, 
  "msg": "Request failed", 
  "response": "HTTP Error 403: Forbidden",
  "status_code": 403, 
  "url": "<https://releases.jfrog.io/artifactory/jfrog-distribution/distribution-deb/2.22.2/jfrog-distribution-2.22.2-deb.tar.gz>"
}
```

Any idea where to look at? I had a guess maybe ansible agent is filtered but it has failed with curl.7.71.1-DEV

Comment: For me it is not reproducible. The task as given is just downloading the correct file, A test with `tar -tf jfrog...` succeed too. You need to provide verbose and debug output for all your steps.

Comment: What's the link with the CDN? Did you mean VPN, maybe?

Comment: > "_I have no problems downloading with curl_" - Did you check the file downloaded by `curl`? Its content might actually be a text of a 403 error page. `curl` doesn't check for the status code by default.

Comment: Also, what do you mean by "ansible agent is filtered"? Ansible is an agentless tool.

Comment: @AlexanderPletnev, he means the following, seen if `-vvv` verbose mode is used: `invocation:
    module_args:
...
      http_agent: ansible-httpget`

Comment: Turned out the problem was that host tried to resolve ipv6 address (I've checked it with netstat -natp | grep pyth, it was stuck at sending syn). I've changed gai.conf to prioritize ipv4 and it fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Turned out the problem was that host tried to resolve ipv6 address (I've checked it with netstat -natp | grep pyth, it was stuck at sending syn). I've changed gai.conf to prioritize ipv4 and it fixed the issue.